# Why is JS code decrementing like number (as expected) but incrementing/concatenating like a string when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, counter, increment, decrement

I have this snippet of code which has to increment and decrement `onclick` by 10. It works fine when decremented but starts concatenating when incremented so the result looks like `1010101010`. I just don't understand why this is happening.

JS

```
 <div class="container">  
  <div class="input-container">
    <div id="minus">-</div>
    <input type="text" id="number" value="0">
    <div id="plus">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

HTML

```
(function(){

  let inputContainer = document.querySelector(".input-container");
  let input = inputContainer.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;
  let minus = inputContainer.firstElementChild;
  let plus = inputContainer.lastElementChild;

  function changeNumber(e) {
      if(e.target === minus) {
          input.value -= 10;
      } else if(e.target === plus) {
          input.value += 10;
      }
  }

  inputContainer.addEventListener("click", changeNumber);
})();
```

How can I fix it?

---

Here is the solution using `parseInt()`!

HTML

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="input-container">
    <div id="minus">-</div>
    <input type="text" id="number" value="0">
    <div id="plus">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function(){

  let inputContainer = document.querySelector(".input-container");
  let input = inputContainer.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;
  let minus = inputContainer.firstElementChild;
  let plus = inputContainer.lastElementChild;

  function changeNumber(e) {
      if(e.target == minus) {
          let inputNumber = parseInt(input.value);
        input.value = inputNumber - 10;
      } else if(e.target == plus) {
          let inputNumber = parseInt(input.value);
        input.value = inputNumber + 10;
      }
  }

  inputContainer.addEventListener("click", changeNumber);
})();
```

Comment: Convert the value to a number.

Comment: it adds fine when incremented by 1

Comment: Because your using a string, the reasons why `-=` works is that you can't use `-=` on a string, so it will automatically convert to a number..

Comment: @Keith oh, I see. thanks mate!

Comment: "it adds fine when incremented by 1" I'm guessing that's with pre/postfix increment operator `++` which is also not valid for strings and also causes the automatic conversion to a number.

Comment: @phuzi converting the value to number seems to work. thanks anyway for answering